# Why is True printed with leading whitespace in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, whitespace

I noticed that in **NumPy 1.13.1**, when a `dtype=np.bool_` array is printed the `True` values always have a leading whitespace.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.asarray([1, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=np.bool_)
array([ True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> #  ^             ^      ^
... # I would have expected: array([True, False, True, True, False], dtype=bool)
...
>>> str(np.asarray([0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=np.bool_))
'[False  True  True False]'
>>> #   ^     ^
... # Again I would have expected: '[False True True False]'
...
>>> repr(np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 0, 0], dtype=np.bool_))
'array([ True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)'
>>> #   ^      ^      ^
... # repr() does it too.
```

Is there any particular reason for formatting it like this?

Comment: Most `numpy` arrays are printed with some sort of weird justification. Try printing `np.array([23.4, 2, 32.33, 1, 0])` and you'll get `array([ 23.4 ,   2.  ,  32.33,   1.  ,   0.  ])` ... not sure what sort of answer you are expecting. Also note, if you print `np.arange(200)` it prints it in a nice, pretty-printed format that looks like a square.

Comment: Some sort of alignment, not peculiar to bools, to maintain readability, considering np arrays are usually large. `True` gets aligned to the width of `False`.

Comment: The extra space ensures that a two-dimensional array of bools is nicely aligned.

Comment: In general, the field width is the same for each element, regardless of the value.  For a bool, the longer value is `False`, so the field width is five characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens for float and bool arrays.

- For float arrays with negative values the extra space ensures alignment (which is nice for multidimensional arrays) leaving space for the negative sign.

  ```
  >>> np.array([-4, 1, 2, -3], dtype=np.float64).reshape(2, 2) 
  array([[-4.,  1.],
         [ 2., -3.]])
  ```
- For bool arrays with multiple values it ensures alignment between `True` and `False`, which are different lengths.

  ```
  >>> np.array([0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=np.bool_).reshape(2, 2) 
  array([[False,  True],
         [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
  ```

There is no particular reason when it is not needed (i.e. all positive float values, single element bool array), and in this case it could be done without.

```
>>> np.array([4, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.float64).reshape(2, 2)
array([[ 4.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.]])
```

There's an [open PR #9130](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9139) on GitHub to make this print spacing more consistent when the additional spacing is not needed with some support, and so it may change in an upcoming version.

Comment: Try it with a two-dimensional array, and you'll see that the spacing makes sense.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, that's where the alignment is maintained as I mention in my answer. Can make that more explicit.

Comment: If you understand that, does it make sense to say "there is no particular reason"?

Comment: Still seems like a strange wording, and it does not seem inconsistent to me, but these are subjective opinions, I guess.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Ehh yeah I kind of put the weird case first, I reorganized. Not sure I've got much to change now though :) thanks for your input.